# If statement problems

Tags: function-construction

I have a function defined as

```
a[x_]:=If[x==0,const,f[x]]
```

where $f(0)\neq const$.

How do I evaluate $a(x)$ such that I just get $f(x)$ without having to put in a specific x value greater than 0? I've tried things like $/;$, Assumptions and Assuming, but haven't been able to do it. This seems like it should be a simple thing, any ideas?

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35522/6588) answer sheds some light on why this might not be as simply as it first seems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TrueQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrueQ.html):

```
a[x_] := If[TrueQ[x == 0], const, f[x]]
```

Or the fourth parameter of [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html):

```
a[x_] := If[x == 0, const, f[x], f[x]]
```

Or formulate your function in two definitions:

```
a[x_] /; x == 0 = const;
a[x_] := f[x]
```

Recommended reading:

- [TrueQ returning False on true statement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55911/121)
- [Evaluating an If condition to yield True/False](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8796/121#9029)

Comment: Or `If[x === 0, ...]` which is what I usually do.

Comment: @CarlWoll ...and what I expressly warn about in the final link in my answer ;^)